# Silverlight VB.Net multiple assignment in single line

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, variable-assignment

I'm new to Silverlight and used to code in VB.Net before. Now I'm trying to assign RepeatButtons' Interval values in a single statement but it sets zero.

```
rbtUp.Interval = rbtLeft.Interval = rbtCenter.Interval = rbtRight.Interval
= rbtDown.Interval = interval
```

This works fine in c# but not in vb.net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264279/multiple-variables)

Comment: Is your variabel interval == 0?

Comment: No it is an integer and it works when the properties are assigned one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing VB.Net with C#.

You can't do what you're trying to do in VB.Net. You need to write multiple statements:

```vb
rbtUp.Interval = interval
rbtLeft.Interval = interval
rbtCenter.Interval = interval
rbtRight.Interval = interval
rbtDown.Interval = interval
```

What happens in your case is that only the first equals sign is the assignment operator, the subsequent ones is the comparison operator. In equivalent C# it would be like this:

```cs
rbtUp.Interval = rbtLeft.Interval == rbtCenter.Interval == rbtRight.Interval == rbtDown.Interval == interval;
```

Which is clearly not what you wanted to do.

It also looks like you don't have Option Strict turned on (since the comparison operator returns a Boolean and Interval is likely an Integer, your code should show a compiler error with Option Strict On when assigning a Boolean to an Integer).

Comment: +1 Especially for `Option Strict`. As a general rule `Option Strict` should be `On`. Can I also add some links to the relevant parts of [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx) and the [language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711633.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I thought this feature was ***so*** cool in **C#** that I wrote a **VB** extension method (`Assign`) to do the same thing.  The semantics are pretty easy to follow; you just call `Assign` on any value to assign it to multiple other variables
i.e.

```
Call True.Assign(b1, b2, b3)
Call 4.1.Assign(d1, d2, d3)
```

etc...

Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices


Namespace Utility
    Public Module MultiAssignExtensionMethod
        ' Multiply assign the same value to 1 (required) or more variables
        <Extension()> _
        Public Function Assign(Of T)(this As T, ByRef first As T, Optional ByRef second As T = Nothing, Optional ByRef third As T = Nothing,
                                    Optional ByRef forth As T = Nothing, Optional ByRef fifth As T = Nothing, Optional ByRef sixth As T = Nothing,
                                    Optional ByRef seventh As T = Nothing, Optional ByRef eighth As T = Nothing, Optional ByRef nineth As T = Nothing,
                                    Optional ByRef tenth As T = Nothing) As T
                            ' I would LIKE to do this as a ParamArray, but it doesn't allow references for basic types....grrr
            first = this
            second = this
            third = this
            forth = this
            fifth = this
            sixth = this
            seventh = this
            eighth = this
            nineth = this
            tenth = this

            Return this     ' For use as assignment and evaluation as Function parameter
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub Main
    Dim outer As Integer = -1
    Dim inner1 As Integer
    Dim inner2 As Integer
    Dim inner3 As Integer
    Dim inner4 As Integer

    inner1 = inner2 = inner3 = inner4 = outer
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", inner1, inner2, inner3, inner4, outer)

End Sub
```

The result is

```
0,0,0,0,-1
```

So it doens't work in VB.NET like in C#

I was curious to find the differences in the IL code from VB.NET and C#.
Looking at the IL code it is obvious the reason for the lack of support in VB.NET

**VB.NET IL code**

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_0002:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0004:  ldloc.1     
IL_0005:  ldloc.2     
IL_0006:  ceq         
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0009:  cgt.un      
IL_000B:  neg         
IL_000C:  ldloc.3     
IL_000D:  ceq         
IL_000F:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0010:  cgt.un      
IL_0012:  neg         
IL_0013:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0015:  ceq         
IL_0017:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0018:  cgt.un      
IL_001A:  neg
```

**C# IL Code for an equivalent example**

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     
IL_0004:  dup         
IL_0005:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0007:  dup         
IL_0008:  stloc.3     
IL_0009:  dup         
IL_000A:  stloc.2     
IL_000B:  stloc.1
```

The VB version goes on comparing the values, thus the problems is the = operator that in VB.NET has a double meaning. In this case is used to compare instead of to assign.

Comment: Correct answer but... wouldn't it be quicker to look in [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx) or the [language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711633.aspx) :)